# Get Instance 'Name' Tag via Python script once IMDSv2 is enabled

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I would like to understand how to fetch an EC2's 'Name' tag value once version 2 of the Instance Metadata Service is enforced over version 1.

When I tried to **describe_instances** under an ec2 client via boto3 my requests returned access denied.

I created the following code to access an EC2's metadata:

```
        http_headers = { 'X-aws-ec2-metadata-token-ttl-seconds': 600, "content-type": "application/json"}
        instance_details = None

        connection = httplib.HTTPConnection('http://169.254.169.254')
        connection.request('PUT', '/latest/api/token', None, http_headers)

        response = connection.getresponse()
        auth_token = response.read()

        http_headers = {'X-aws-ec2-metadata-token': auth_token, "content-type": "application/json"}

        connection.request('GET', '/2016-06-30/dynamic/instance-identity/document/', None, http_headers)
        response = connection.getresponse()

        instance_details = response.read()
```

This of course allows me to attain the instance Id, region, etc. but I need a way to get the set of tags associated with an instance.

I haven't seen a way to add a token to a boto3 client. If anyone knows a work around please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: Attach `ec2:DescribeInstances` to the IAM role associated to the EC2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Access Denied` error indicates that AWS has rejected your call to `DescribeInstances()`.

If an IAM Role has been assigned to the instance, then add the `ec2:DescribeInstances` permission to the IAM Role. The Amazon EC2 Instance Metadata Service will be used to retrieve credentials for IAM Role.

If you are using credentials from an IAM User, the add the permission to that IAM User.

Tags are not provided by the Instance Metadata service.

Answer (score 1):

Since Jan, 2022 it's possible to get instance tag name without IAM changes. But `InstanceMetadataTags` option should be enabled for particular EC2 instance.

The desired tag will be retrieved by `GET http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/tags/instance/Name`

To allow access to tags in instance metadata at launch using the AWS CLI

```
aws ec2 run-instances \
    --image-id ami-0abcdef1234567890 \
    --instance-type c3.large \
    ...
    --metadata-options "InstanceMetadataTags=enabled"
```

To allow access to tags in instance metadata on a running or stopped instance using the AWS CLI

```
aws ec2 modify-instance-metadata-options \
    --instance-id i-123456789example \
    --instance-metadata-tags enabled
```

See also https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Using_Tags.html#work-with-tags-in-IMDS